# Куда нужно вставить self.painter.end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, qt5, pyqt5

Вылетает ошибка, а конкретнее segmentation fault, не понимаю в чем ошибка. И второй вопрос как сделать чтобы фигура обрисовывалась после background-image? То есть фигура будет нарисована, но если есть background-image ее будет не видно, что с этим можно сделать? может мне стоит использовать другой способ создания фигур?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQuick
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt




class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        self.setFixedSize(1300, 800)
        self.setUpdatesEnabled(True)
        self.setObjectName("main")


    def paintEvent(self, e):
        self.painter = QPainter(self)
        self.painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.green, 8, Qt.DashLine))
        self.painter.drawEllipse(40, 40, 400, 400)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    wind = MainWindow()
    wind.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

в этом коде не работает

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQuick
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView
import sys

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.green, 8, Qt.DashLine))
        painter.drawEllpise(40, 40, 400, 400)
        painter.end()

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        self.setFixedSize(1300, 800)
        self.setUpdatesEnabled(True)
        self.setStyleSheet(open("style.qss", "r").read())
        self.setObjectName("main")

class Login(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    switch_window = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 180)
        self.setWindowTitle('Login')
        self.setStyleSheet(open("style.qss", "r").read())


        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(135, 100, 130, 40))
        self.button.setText("Login")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.login)

    def login(self):
        self.switch_window.emit()

class Controller:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def show_login(self):
        self.login = Login()
        self.login.switch_window.connect(self.show_main)
        self.login.show()

    def show_main(self):
        self.window = MainWindow()
        self.login.close()
        self.window.show()

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    controller = Controller()
    controller.show_login()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> в этом коде не работает

Замените в `MainWindow` на:

```
def paintEvent(self, e):
    painter = QPainter(self)
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.green, 8, Qt.DashLine))
    painter.drawEllipse(40, 40, 400, 400)
```

Comment: не подскажите как нарисовать фигуру чтобы на нем были объекты, а саму фигуру так, чтобы она была поверх background-image?

Comment: Используйте drawImage/drawPixmap (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawing-pixmaps-and-images) передавая `self.rect()`, например: `painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), pixmap, self.rect())`. В QPixmap/QImage загружаете вашу картинку

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQuick
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        self.setFixedSize(1300, 800)
        self.setUpdatesEnabled(True)
        self.setObjectName("main")

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)                                         # +
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.green, 8, Qt.DashLine))
        painter.drawEllipse(40, 40, 400, 400)
        painter.end()                                               # +

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    wind = MainWindow()
    wind.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По какой-то причине, непонятной мне, когда я вставляю это в этот код - это перестает работать

Comment: отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Можно просто `painter = QPainter(self)`, тогда ни `begin`, ни `end` не нужны

Comment: а как поместить ее выше чем background Image  но ниже чем объекты?